# Calculate Character represented by Binary

Tags: haskell

I have an `[[Int]]` with value such as `[[0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1],[0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0]]`.

I need to convert this to the ascii representation such as "ab".

Could somebody give me some pointers about how I would go about doing this in Haskell?

Comment: Hint: how to convert a binary list to its numeric equivalent?

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with?  What have you tried (or thought about trying) so far?

Answer (score 1):

You can:

1. Write a function that converts a list of integers (binary) into a base 10 integer (Int)
2. compose that function with [`chr`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Data-Char.html#v:chr) from the module `Data.Char`
3. use `map` to apply those composed functions (which convert binary to base 10 and then to a character) to map over the list of binary reps and turn it into a list of characters -- which is a String.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a `foldl` over a list to calculate its integer value, then use `chr` to interpret the integer as a unicode code point (of which ascii is a subset).

```
λ> import Data.Char (chr)
λ> fmap (chr . foldl (\x y -> 2*x + y) 0) [[0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1],[0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0]]
"ab"
```